# adding space in a column of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, design-patterns, replace, gsub

I want to replace "Qu.:" with "Qu. :" for the entire column. But below code doesnt run :(

```
emp = c('Min.   :2014-07-17 00:00:00','1st Qu.:2014-07-17 00:00:00')
df <- data.frame(emp)

for (i in (1 : nrow(df))) { gsub("Qu.:", "Qu. :", df[i,1] ) }
```

Comment: `sub` and `gsub` are vectorized, so how about `df$emp <- sub("Qu.:", "Qu. :", df$emp)`

Comment: your proximal problem is that you aren't replacing anything.  If you want to do it the hard way you can use `df[i,1] <- gsub(...)` in your `for` loop -- but @RichardScriven's advice is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sub` and `gsub` are vectorized, so no need for a loop.  Give this a try:

```
df$emp <- sub("Qu.:", "Qu. :", df$emp, fixed = TRUE)
```

`sub` matches and replaces only the first occurrence, which is what it seems like what you're doing on that column.  It can be more efficient than `gsub` and is more appropriate if you're only matching the first occurrence.